# Associate a file type to a specific Excel workbook

Tags: windows, microsoft-excel

I have a special extension (*.dia*) for storing electricity diagrams. Inside these files are binary, created by an Excel library (.xlam). For fast viewing of a diagram, I would like to bind the *.dia* extension to a specific Excel **file** (e.g. *diagramViewer.xlsm*), so that whenever I double click a *.dia*, this *diagramViewer.xlsm* opens up and reads the binary file (the path of which would most likely be passed as a command line argument) - is this possible?

Comment: I would use a scripting language like [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to write a small script that openes your file in excel and performs the secondary actions and then link the .dia extension to this script. If it's possible directly in Excel depends on how the diagramViever.xlsm works.

Comment: I've already written an answer that "might" work but how does the xlsm read the .dia? Can you post some pictures?

Comment: Yes, the xlsm reads the .dia file. As soon as the xlsm recognizes a .dia file in the command ine arguments, it reads the .dia file using a vba library and show the .dia file content.

Answer (score 0):

I actually found a way to do this, however I haven't tested it. It dates back from my Windows 98 days, but it should work. I'm basing myself on this [Microsoft DevNet](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms977165.aspx) post and on the workings of the command line as described by [ss64.com](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html).

1 - **Accessing the file type.**

To do this, open **File Options**. On Windows XP it's a matter of, on **Explorer**, clicking the **Tools** menu and then clicking **File Options**.
On Vista/7, I'm basing myself on what is written [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-is/windows7/change-folder-options). Quoting:

> Open Folder Options by clicking the Start button, clicking Control Panel, clicking Appearance and Personalization, and then clicking Folder Options.

Go to **File Types** and there find the **.dia** extension, as shown on here for a .bmp.

> [image: Folder Options - File Types]

2 - **Adding the command**

Now press **Advanced** and then create a new action.

> [image: Advanced - Edit File Type]
>   [image: New Action dialog]

Write a name for the action (say `Open in .dia and Excel`). Now here's the catch: The file name is given as an optional argument called `%1`. Using the replacement syntax shown on the second link, in the "Application used to perform action" you should have something in the likes of the following:

```
excel "%1:.dia=.xlsm%"
```

This assumes the folder excel is at is at the %PATH% variable, which it should. Otherwise, just write the full path, inside `"` marks.This will *supposedly* replace the file extension from .dia to .xlsm. Some care is needed, as it will replace **every** instance of .dia for .xlsm. If you have a file name like `some.diary.dia` it will be replaced to `some.xlsmry.xlsm`.

**This also means that the Excel file must have the same name as the .dia file.**

You can make the action as default after you press OK by selecting the action you made and clicking on Set Default.

EDIT: I've written this based on the first impression that what the OP wanted to do was to open both the program that opened the .dia and excel. The answer is incomplete, as for it to be complete it would require a batch. However, I'm waiting for the OP's response.

Comment: Hello, I will immediately try - its just that on Windows 7 this nice window for defining actions for filetypes is missing..

Comment: @Dan please answer my other comment. This might work, but I would need to know more.