# how to turning back to default open with option .cfg

Tags: firefox

I was trying to open a ".CFG" file with a notepad and I accidentally forgot to UN-tick the box near "always use the selected program to open this kind of file". After click OK all my applications such as Mozilla Firefox, Google chrome, real player, Skype, media player everything changed the icon to NOTEPAD.... 
Please help me to return back to the default program.
I tried everything what i can.. But it didn`t change anything.

Comment: Technically, there is no default program to open .cfg files. Besides, the programs that depend on those files will work as always. What OS are you using, as it will affect the solution proposed?

Comment: @DoktoroReichard: There *is* a default program if you check the "Always use this program..." box when asked for a program.

Comment: @grawity I know about *that*. What I meant was that no Windows version I know of, reads .cfg files by default and off the box. I wrote an answer for a question that dealt with file associations, you can read it [here](http://superuser.com/a/638185/228536). I ***suppose*** that removing the file's actions would remove the default program, but I can't be sure.

Answer (score 0):

Go to menu, Edit / Preferences / Applications and select "Always ask" for that file type..
(it is dependant on Firefox and OS; under Windows I think it is Tools / Options instead of Edit / Preferences or something like that)

Comment: If the user has the Menu Bar in Firefox turned off then they get the Firefox button (this is the default setting). It then becomes **Firefox > Preferences > Preferences** for GNU/Linux flavors, and **Firefox > Options > Options** for Windows.

Comment: Although an accurate answer, I didn't understand that the OP's problem was related to *how* Firefox downloads things. It was about the icon and the default program Windows uses to open .cfg files (that doesn't exist).